# Return all subdocs to Jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, pug

I have a document in MongoDB that includes subdocuments, `destinations` as a field. I want to return this data back to my Jade template, however, this doesn't seem to be working.

User document:

```
{ _id: 582c7a1c60cd0447daa64b5e,
  firstName: 'a',
  lastName: 'a',
  username: 'a@a.com',
  homeAirport: 'syd',
  __v: 7,
  destinations: 
   [ { airport: 'rhys', month: 'rhys', _id: 5837165c87373103f13921f9 },
     { airport: 'bob', month: 'bob', _id: 583716ae79f2e80498aa33ef },
     { airport: 'check',
       month: 'ceck',
       _id: 583716d4ba757104b0fcc8dd }
```

Jade template

```
if (user)
  include addDestinations.jade
  p The email address is #{user.username}
  p My first name is #{user.firstName}
  p My last name is #{user.lastName}
  p I fly from #{user.homeAirport}
  p I wanna go to #{user.destinations.aiport}
  a(href='/logout') Log out
  div
    - console.log(user)
  div
```

How do I call the subdocs and iterate through it's results to render into html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jade iteration](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html)

```
if (user)
  include addDestinations.jade
  p The email address is #{user.username}
  p My first name is #{user.firstName}
  p My last name is #{user.lastName}
  p I fly from #{user.homeAirport}
  p
   each dest in user.destinations
    // Must use =
    p= dest.airport
  a(href='/logout') Log out
  div
    - console.log(user)
  div
```

Comment: Thanks iKoala, that makes sense. I just updated the answer to include the correct syntax

Comment: nice catch, i forgot about that :)